# Can not use the wheel of the mouse to zoom after 'setView'

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I use `setView` in the startup process of Forge.
After Viewer is started, the camera is set correctly, however it can not zoom with mouse wheel.
How can I fix it? My current code:

```
MyAwesomeExtension.prototype.onObjectTreeCreated = function () {
    // use THREE.Vector3() to pos, target
    _viewer.navigation.setView(pos, target);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following, works fine. I'm using Viewer `v6` (latest, as of August/18).

```
// for testing, first I stored this info
var p = _viewer.navigation.getPosition()
var t = _viewer.navigation.getTarget()


// now I move pan/zon as a user...
// later I call
_viewer.navigation.setView(p, t)
```

Comment: Dear Augusto,
I tried your source code, and I resolved the issue.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: great, glad to hear! remember to "accept as an answer" to close it.